# date of birth validation if user is above 16

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to validate if the user is above 16 but it is failing the condition everytime 
here is my code

trying to add a condition to check if user is atleast 16 years old

```
if (($("#year").val(), month, day)) {
```

Here is the try

```
if (($("#year").val(), month, day) <= getAge(new Date())) {
```

where getAge is a function like this

```
function getAge(DOB) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(DOB);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }    
    return age;
}
```

but it is still going into condition if i enter date as 10/22/2001

Comment: change to `if (getAge($("#year").val()) < 16)`

Comment: The Date of Birth is today?

Comment: why do you send Date() into `getAge`? Welcome to SO. Hopefully we won't see a new profile like JINT for your next question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your getAge function returns 16 as per your '10/22/2001' example.

But your if statement is strange. You don't need to find out someones birthdate if they were born today.

You can use:

```
if (getAge($("#year").val()) < 16) {
    // the person is 15 or under
}
else {
    // the person is 16 or over.
}
```

Comment: i also need to condider day and month, not only year

Answer (score 0):

Your question and the given code is not that clear. I believe IsDate is a function to check if the input is a valid date, If yes pass that value to getAge function.

```
if(getAge(**enter your DOB**)>=16){
//write your code if the age is greater than or equal to 16
}
```